# count unique values by row across selected columns of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a dataset of students reporting the first, last, and favorite books they read over the summer...

```
d <- data.table(
      student_id = 1:4,
      first_book = c('Dune','Starship Troopers', 
                     'The Moon is a Harsh Mistress', NA_character_),
      last_book  = c('The Martian Chronicles','Foundation',
                     'The Moon is a Harsh Mistress', NA_character_),
      favorite_book = c('I, Robot','Foundation',
                        'The Moon is a Harsh Mistress', NA_character_) )
```

... and I want to know for every student how many unique books this report includes.  (I want to know that Student1 read three or more books, Student2 two or more books, Student3 exactly one book, and Student4 zero.)

I know I can use `melt` and `length(unique()` like so:

```
melt(d, id.vars='student_id', 
     value.name='title')[, .(count = length(unique(title[!is.na(title)]))),
                          keyby=student_id]
```

But the melt is not necessary, and I can use `apply` and `length(unique())` like so:

```
d[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))), 
  .SDcols = c('first_book', 'last_book', 'favorite_book'),
  keyby = student_id] # or by .I if one row per student
```

Is the `apply` the preferred idiomatic data.table approach, or is there a better way to write this?

Comment: `melt` may not be necessary but I would assume it's faster. Also please note (since 1.9.6) you can more efficiently replace `length(unique(...))` with `uniqueN(...)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks -- wasn't aware of `uniqueN` but will use.  Realize your comment was not an answer but interested in why `melt` is presumably faster if you care to elaborate.  I know that `melt` is optimized for data.table, but the `apply(.SD)` approach is taught in Matt Dowle's DataCamp course -- if memory serves.  I'll run a benchmark tomorrow and post results here.

Comment: I could well be wrong. Would be interested to see. I know Matt and Arun have plans to build in some row-wise functions at some point, so maybe they're teaching `apply` for now in preparation for that?